# Having some issues with .sub and .gsub

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run some Oracle performance tests. I have the following file:

**orcheck.txt**

`select * from mf_aj where uid_lo in ('OOO',) or uid_lo in`

I'd like to duplicate the `'OOO'` 100 times, and then duplicate each `or uid_lo in (...)` an additional 100 times.

```
File.open('orcheck.txt' , 'r') do |f|
  i = 0
  contents = f.read.gsub("'OOO',") { |m|
    m.sub("'OOO',", (m * 1000))
  }

  theClause = contents[/\((.*)in/]
  contents.gsub(theClause, (theClause * 100))

  contents.gsub("'OOO',") { |m|
    m.sub('OOO', (i += 1).to_s)
  }

  File.write('orcheck.txt', contents.to_s)
end
```

The first `.gsub` works fine, and duplicates the `'OOO'` 1000 times. However the following .gsub for `theClause` and replacing the `'OOO'` with increasing ints does not. Could someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line

```
  contents.gsub(theClause, (theClause * 100))
```

does not modify `contents`.  It returns a modified String.

```
  contents.gsub!(theClause, (theClause * 100))
```

will modify `contents` itself however.  By convention, ruby methods that end with ! are methods which modify the object in some way, and others do not.  It's not absolute, but it holds true a fair chunk of the time.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to use a regex here.

```
 > 100.times.collect { |n| "'%03d'" % n }.join(',')
=> "'000','001','002','003','004', etc
```

Therefore:

```
s = 100.times.collect { |n| "'%03d'" % n }.join(',')
q = "select * from mf_aj where uid_lo in (#{s})"
```

Modify to fit your actual query, and use a similar technique to create the superfluous trailing `in`.

As to the rest, I'm baffled: you time the text file creation, which has nothing to do with Oracle. It's really not clear what you're trying to do from the description, IMO.

Comment: Sorry, the timing in this isn't part of the performance - I'll take that bit out.